# how can I put an element always in top on a image with transform property

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

so I'm trying to make a "like" button, but my images have a transform property on hover, and this make my like button go to behind the image.

when I'm not hovering:

[image: image1]

when I'm hovering:

[image: image2]

My css code using styled components:

```
const Container = styled.div `
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 5px;

  .heart {
    position: absolute;
    color: #FF4040;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    border: none;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
    img{
        flex:1;
        width: 165px;
        height: 220px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        
      }
    .heart:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    img:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
        opacity:0.4;
        position: sticky;
    }
  }

`;


export default Container;
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
z-index : 100;
```

in CSS to the like button.